# Oracle Fusion REST API to extract Absence details based on Start Date, End date and Person number

Tags: rest, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am trying to extract All absence details for one person number based on start date and End date. So total Input parameter are person number or person ID, Absence Start Date and Absence End date. I am using below API syntex, but it's not working. If I try to extract all the absence details based on absence start date and end date then I can get all the information. But I am unable to get based on person number along with abs start date and end date,

https://xxxxxxx.oraclecloud.com:443/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences?finder=findByPersonIdAbsStartAndEndDate;personId=30000000222228,startDate=2023-01-01,endDate=2023-12-31

Please Let me know if anyone has faced this and resolved it